# Calculate on form change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not that pro with javascript, so I am here for help. I want to dynamicly calculate a price on change of form elements...

the HTML Structure:

```
<div class="semOrder">
        <h1>Calculate price</h1>
        <form name="bestelling" id="bestelling" method="GET" action="/offerte-aanvragen/" style="margin-top:10px" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="p" value="S2V1a2VudGVudCA1JiMyMTU7NSw1bQ==" hidden="">
    <input name="c" value="TGVnZXJ0ZW50ZW4=" hidden="">
    <select name="d" style="color:white;" class="valid">
        <option value="0" selected="">Aantal dagen:</option>
        <option value="1">1 day</option>
        <option value="2">2 days</option>
        <option value="3">3 days</option>
        <option value="4">4 days</option>
        <option value="5">5 days</option>
        <option value="6">6 days</option>
        <option value="7">7 days</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <p>Aantal: <input name="a" value="1" style="width:20px!important"> tenten</p>
    <p>Prijs: <input id="priceContainer" value="24,95"></p>
    <input id="persoonShower" type="submit" value="offerte aanvragen">
</form>

    </div>
```

Now I need it that when the field with name `d`or `a` is being changed it should calculate with `(d * a)+5` and then return the amount in `#priceContainer`...

A jQuery approche is prefferd...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var $d = $('select[name="d"]'),
        $a = $('input[name="a"]'),
        $price = $('#priceContainer');

    function calculate() {
      var output = (parseInt($d.val(), 10) * parseFloat($a.val())) + 5;
      $price.val(output);
    }

    $d.change(calculate);
    $a.keyup(calculate);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="semOrder">
  <h1>Calculate price</h1>
  <form name="bestelling" id="bestelling" method="GET" action="/offerte-aanvragen/" style="margin-top:10px" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="p" value="S2V1a2VudGVudCA1JiMyMTU7NSw1bQ==" hidden="">
    <input name="c" value="TGVnZXJ0ZW50ZW4=" hidden="">
    <select name="d" style="color:white;" class="valid">
      <option value="0" selected="">Aantal dagen:</option>
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
      <option value="4">4 days</option>
      <option value="5">5 days</option>
      <option value="6">6 days</option>
      <option value="7">7 days</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Aantal:
      <input name="a" value="1" style="width:20px!important">tenten</p>
    <p>Prijs:
      <input id="priceContainer" value="24,95">
    </p>
    <input id="persoonShower" type="submit" value="offerte aanvragen">
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup and on change both to get live change.It would be better if you give a class to a,d field to make selection a bit easy.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name='d'],[name='a']").on("change keyup", function() {
    $("#priceContainer").val(($("[name='d']").val() * $("[name='a']").val()) + 5)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="semOrder">
  <h1>Calculate price</h1>
  <form name="bestelling" id="bestelling" method="GET" action="/offerte-aanvragen/" style="margin-top:10px" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="p" value="S2V1a2VudGVudCA1JiMyMTU7NSw1bQ==" hidden="">
    <input name="c" value="TGVnZXJ0ZW50ZW4=" hidden="">
    <select name="d" style="color:white;" class="valid">
      <option value="0" selected="">Aantal dagen:</option>
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
      <option value="4">4 days</option>
      <option value="5">5 days</option>
      <option value="6">6 days</option>
      <option value="7">7 days</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Aantal:
      <input name="a" value="1" style="width:20px!important">tenten</p>
    <p>Prijs:
      <input id="priceContainer" value="24,95">
    </p>
    <input id="persoonShower" type="submit" value="offerte aanvragen">
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery `.change()` and `.on()` functionality in order to dynamically pull and calculate the values. A quick way to do this would be the following.

```
$('select[name="d"]').change(function(){

    var d = $(this).val();

    var a = $('input[name="a"]').val();

    var total = (a * d) + 5;

    $('#priceContainer').val(total);

});

 $('input[name="a"]').on('input',function(){

        var a = $(this).val();

        var d = $('select[name="d"]').val();

        var total = (a * d) + 5;

        $('#priceContainer').val(total);

});
```

here is the working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1vqu4ev8/1/